# "Can't GET /XXX" error while using swagger-express

Tags: rest, express, swagger

I'm using swagger-express for making RESTful API. Base /hello route works fine, but I tried to add some more sophisticated one, with database connection etc. Whenever I tried to send GET request on that route, I would get "Cannot GET /xxx". I triple-checked everything and it looked fine, so I decided to make an exact copy of `/hello` route called `/test`, just changed some variables - doesn't work too, same error. Here is my `/test` route in `swagger.yaml`

```
/test:
# binds a127 app logic to a route
x-swagger-route-controller: test-route
get:
  description: route for testing
  # used as the method name of the controller
  operationId: test
  responses:
    "200":
      description: Success
      schema:
        # a pointer to a definition
        $ref: "#/definitions/TestResponse"
    # responses may fall trough to errors    
    default:
      description: Error
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
```

and here is my test-route.js controller

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  test
};

function test(req, res) {

  res.json("Test Route");
}
```

As I said, it's almost exact copy of /hello default route, all other files in swagger project were untouched.

Comment: Is this how your YAML is actually indented? Lines after `/test` must be indented to the right of `/test`, otherwise it's invalid.

Comment: Well, i just found you that I wrote `x-swagger-route-controller` instead of `x-swagger-routeS-controller` and that was the whole problem.